# Scanning for Akka Actors

Tags: scala, network-programming, actor, akka

I have a node which may be running multiple instances of a server (Akka remote actor).  I would like clients to be able to scan a range of ports on a given node looking for live servers.

I wrote this method in my client actor:

```
  private def scanHost(serverHost: String) = {
    val initialPort = 36627
    val portsToScan = (initialPort until initialPort + 32).toList
    val tries = portsToScan map {
      port  ⇒ remote.actorFor("EnMAS-service", serverHost, port) ? Discovery
    }
    val replies = tries filter { future  ⇒ {
      try { 
        future.get match {
          case reply: DiscoveryReply  ⇒ true
          case _  ⇒ false
        }
      }
      catch { case _  ⇒ false }
    }}
    ClientManager.ScanResult(replies map {_.get.asInstanceOf[DiscoveryReply]})
  }
```

I am wondering, is there a more idiomatic way to get this done?  I couldn't find much on this, although I imagine this use case is fairly common.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sounds like you're after a cluster. Until Akka 2.1 ships (with built in cluster support), you can use something like [ZooKeeper](https://zookeeper.apache.org/) or [JGroups](http://www.jgroups.org/) or otherwise to have nodes register when they start and deregister when they leave (or timeout)

Comment: Yep, essentially I am setting up clusters on the fly where each "cluster" has an arbitrary head node that synchronizes its peers.  I was hoping to stay within the Scala standard libs and the Akka framework to avoid introducing another dependency.  I should be covered by the supervisors currently built into Akka but I look forward to the forthcoming cluster support.  Thanks for the info.

Comment: Well, you can ad-hoc it by having a rendezvous node that you dial in to and that keeps track of clients. Distributed error detection is far from trivial though, which is why we are releasing clustering as a prime feature for 2.1